# How to delete an object from within itself?

Tags: php

I have an array of objects (A) which has an array of objects (B) inside it.
I'm trying to move B to a different object in array A.
I'm trying to use this:

```
public function killToken($a) {
    array_push($a->tokens,$this);  // Put this token in new array (works)
    unset($this);                  // Remove token from this array (does not work)
}
```

I call this function via: `$b->killToken($a);`

I've tried several variations on this, but I just can't figure out how to get rid of the object from inside itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$this` has no context within an array.  I don't think you're explaining your problem very clear.  If you can, try to provide an example of your data structure.

Comment: Ah.. okay.  So `$b` is an object that has a property which is an array of other objects?  And `$a` is the object that you want to remove from that array property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you're breaking encapsulation by trying to do this:

```
array_push($a->tokens,$this);
```

You should not be modifying `$a`'s state from within `$b`.  You should only modify `$b`'s state from within `$b`, and tell `$a` to modify its own state:

```
$b->killToken($a); // only removes $a from $b->tokens
$a->addToken($b); // adds $b to $a->tokens
```

This is one of the basic principles of OO design.

**Edit:**  That being said, `unset($foo)` is not how you remove an element from an array.  You can [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for the element, which will give you the index, and then you can unset the index like `unset($array[$index])`, and there are a few other different methods, as well.